# Ubuntu 14.04.02 downloads lts utopic kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates

So an update just came up for me asking to install kernel stuff, and I looked into it. It turns out it was going to install the 14.10 (utopic) lts kernel (`linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`) along with the normal `linux-image-3.16.0-44-generic`.
Is this normal procedure or should I be worried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu 14.04, it is normal.

In version 14.04.2 there is `linux-generic-lts-utopic` kernel meta package by default.

And 3.16 kernel version is indeed the "utopic" line of kernels from 14.10.

You can read about [LTS HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

But it depends on which point version you installed initially.

If you installed 14.04 or 14.04.1, it has been apdated to 14.04.2, but the kernel major version stays as it was 3.13.

Comment: Just wanted to be safe!